# How can I use ROW_NUMBER() if the column name is not identified?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create row number but I don't want to use any specified column (or column name not identified). Something like below

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '*'), * FROM DIM_BRANCH
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, you want to assign a unique random number to each row?

Comment: actually i don't want this. i only want to implement row number with * column--(column name unknown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@rowcount), * FROM DIM_BRANCH
```

If you want a more random behavior :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()), * FROM DIM_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Select Null)), * FROM DIM_BRANCH
```

Comment: you forgot a `,` there :)